# ¿Como puedo borrar en un String caracteres repetidos con una expresion Regular?

Tags: java, string, condiciones, bucles, replaceall

he estado buscando un metodo para borrar en un String caracteres repetidos con una expresion Regular sin usar For, While nada de ciclos, y para ello busque en este sitio web esta solucion

[Sitio Web](https://aprenderaprogramar.com/foros/index.php?topic=812.0)

Esta expresion

```
cadena = cadena.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1");
```

Pero lo implemente en mi codigo y no me funciona

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class BoyOrGirl {
    
        static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
     
    
           public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
                String text = br.readLine();
        
                text = text.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1");
                System.out.println(text.length());
        
                if (text.length() % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("CHAT WITH HER!");
        
                } else {
                    System.out.println("IGNORE HIM!");
                }
            }
        }
```

pero en la solucion no me borra los elementos repetidos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que el tamanio deberia ser 6

Si alguien me puede ayudar en resolver esto estaria agradecido, y seria que me podrian pasar un documento, libro o sitio web para analizar y profundicar en el tema de las expresiones regulares e irregulares. Gracias :D

Comment: ¿Por qué supones que tu expresión regular será de orden O(1)? Por cierto, el orden no es lo mismo que la velocidad, un O(1) puede ser más lento que un O(n^2), los O solo nos dicen como evoluciona el código *cuando n tiende a infinito*.

Comment: porque cuando no tienen for son O(1) ¿no?, pero bueno necesito  borrar en un String caracteres repetidos con una expresion Regular me podrias decir que esta mal y que toca arreglar porfavor

Comment: Prueba con esta expresión: (.*)(?=.*\1) captura todas las letras repetidas. Deja solo la ultima. Si quieres que deje la primera y borre las demás repetidas haces un reverse string, aplicas la expresión y vuelves hacer un reverse string. Quizá te ayude. Ah reemplazas con '' (vacio)

Comment: Hola, he logrado realizar el proceso usando recursividad en java, la verdad es que con la expresión regular que tienes te sirve solo si se repiten las letras de manera continua, pero si se encuentra el caracter repetido salteado no lo detecta. Si no es obligación hacerlo con expresiones puedes decirme y te comparto el código que realicé.

Comment: Que ejecutes la expresión regular en una sola línea no significa que sea O(1). También puedes poner un código con veinte for anidados y encapsularlo en un método; cuando llames al método verás una única línea pero no por eso sera O(1)... Para calcular el orden de tu código tienes que saber el orden de los métodos que llamas. Y ya te digo yo que una regex no es O(1) ya que como mínimo tiene que recorrer todos los elementos del String.

Comment: @SJuan76 gracias por aclararme la notacion Big O, ¿pero entonces cuando recorre el String seria O(n)?

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Gracias ya lo cambie y me funciona de maravilla :D.

Comment: Lo pongo como respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esta expresión:

```
(.*)(?=.*\1)
```

Captura todas las letras repetidas. Deja solo la ultima. Si quieres que la primera quede  y elimines las repetidas después de ésta tendrias que hacer primero un string.reverse, aplicar la sustitución  de la expresión y luego restaurar con otra string.reverse.

El reemplazo lo tienes que hacer como un caracter vacio o nulo: ''.